# Two or more services on same port behind NAT

Tags: routing, nat, port-forwarding

I think this question is not first but all what I see don't useful for me. Ok, for example I have my network behind NAT where I want setup two http servers on the different hosts. How I can perform routing?
How I understand I can forward all traffic which came to 80 port on service which can handle request forwarding by domain's name, but which service can do this?

**p.s** And yes, I dont wanna vpn )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For HTTP you need a [reverse HTTP proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) which would parse incoming HTTP requests and pass them to different backend servers according to the `Host` header (and maybe even path — so you can serve `http://example.com/foo/` and `http://example.com/bar/` from different backend servers if you need).

You can use either a specialized proxy software which supports reverse proxy operation (Squid, Varnish, …) or an HTTP server with reverse proxying capabilities (nginx, Apache, …). Most of them can also perform other functions like caching and load balancing in addition to simple proxying.